# Understanding format of data in scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to work with multi-label text classification using scikit-learn in Python 3.x. I have data in libsvm format which I am loading using `load_svmlight_file` module. The data format is like this.

> - 314523,165538,76255 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:2 13:1
> - 410523,230296,368303,75145 8:1 19:2 22:1 24:1 29:1 63:1 68:1 69:3 76:1 82:1 83:1 84:1

Each of these lines corresponds to one document. The first three numbers are the labels, and the next entries are feature numbers with their values. Each feature corresponds to a word.

I am loading the data using this script.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file

X,Y = load_svmlight_file("train.csv", multilabel = True, zero_based = True)
```

My question is, that when I see the format of data by doing for example, `print (X[0])`, I get this output.

> (0, 1)    1.0
>
> (0, 2)    1.0
>
> (0, 3)    1.0
>
> (0, 4)    1.0
>
> (0, 5)    1.0
>
> (0, 6)    1.0
>
> (0, 7)    1.0
>
> (0, 8)    1.0
>
> (0, 9)    1.0
>
> (0, 10)   1.0
>
> (0, 11)   1.0
>
> (0, 12)   2.0
>
> (0, 13)   1.0

I don't understand the meaning of this format. Shouldn't the format be something like this.

```
> 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13

> 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   2   1
```

I am new to scikit. I would appreciate some help in this regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with multilabel classification per se. The feature matrix `X` that you get from `load_svmlight_file` is a [SciPy CSR matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html), as explained in the docs, and those print in a rather unfortunate format:

```
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> X = csr_matrix([[0, 0, 1], [2, 3, 0]])
>>> X
<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> X.toarray()
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 0]])
>>> print(X)
  (0, 2)    1
  (1, 0)    2
  (1, 1)    3
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I could not find this in scikit-learn documentation. I still can't understand how this CSR Matrix is structured. Can I convert it back to a normal array?

Comment: @Sasha It's in the [docstring](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file.html). You can convert to array with `X.toarray()`, as I showed in the example.