# Test Data Prediction Error in SciPy sparse matrix

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn, test-data, multilabel-classification

I input data in LIBSVM format like this into a SciPy sparse matrix. The training set is multi-label and multi-class as described in this question I asked:
[Understanding format of data in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380426/understanding-format-of-data-in-scikit-learn)

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
X,Y = load_svmlight_file("train-subset100.csv.csv", multilabel = True, zero_based = True)
```

Then I employ `OneVsRestClassifier` with `LinearSVC` to train the data.

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

Now when I want to test the data, I do the following.

```
X_, Y_ = load_svmlight_file("train-subset10.csv", multilabel = True, zero_based = False)
predicted = clf.predict(X_)
```

Here it gives me error. I dump the traceback here as it is.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test.py", line 36, in
>
> predicted = clf.predict(X_)
>
> File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 151, in predict
>
> return predict_ovr(self.estimators_, self.label_binarizer_, X)
>
> File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 67, in predict_ovr
>
> Y = np.array([_predict_binary(e, X) for e in estimators])
>
> File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/multiclass.py", line 40, in _predict_binary
>
> return np.ravel(estimator.decision_function(X))
>
> File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 728, in decision_function
>
> self._check_n_features(X)
>
> File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 748, in _check_n_features
>
> X.shape[1]))
>
> ValueError: X.shape[1] should be 3421, not 690.

I do not understand why is it looking for more features when the input format is a sparse matrix? How can I get it to predict test labels correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue myself. The problem was that loading datasets one by one using SVMLIGHT/LIBSVM format expects the training matrices to have feature set of the same size. So there are two workarounds for it. One is that you input all data at once using `load_svmlight_files` command.

```
X,Y,X_,Y_ = load_svmlight_files("train-subset100.csv", "train-subset10.csv",... 

multilabel = True, zero_based = False)
```

Secondly you can mention the number of features explicitly.

```
X,Y=load_svmlight_file("train-subset100.csv",multilabel=True, zero_based = False)
X_,Y_ = load_svmlight_file("train-subset10.csv", n_features = X.shape[1],... 
multilabel = True, zero_based = False, )
```